# Sort an Array by keys value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => PaddyPower
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T09:28:36
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 4/5
            [CP] => 17/20
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.85
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => BetFair
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T09:59:12
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 1/25
            [CP] => 43/50
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.86
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => BetVictor
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T10:29:38
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 869/1000
            [CP] => 869/1000
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.87
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => BetFred
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T09:28:30
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 4/5
            [CP] => 17/20
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.85
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => CoralBet
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T09:28:36
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 73/100
            [CP] => 83/100
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.83
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => Bet365
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T09:35:59
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 73/100
            [CP] => 83/100
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.83
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => WilliamHill
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T09:48:17
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 4/5
            [CP] => 83/100
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.83
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => SkyBet
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T09:29:48
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 67/100
            [CP] => 83/100
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.83
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Outcome] => 1
            [Bookmaker] => Ladbrokes
            [Updated] => 2015-01-19T09:29:48
            [Bet] => 1
            [SP] => 3/4
            [CP] => 4/5
            [line] => 
            [Decimal] => 0.8
        )

)
```

and I am attempting to sort it by the "Decimal" key's value.

I have created a function to do a sort by the Decimal value, But for some reason as you can see by my above array, It isn't quite sorting it, In that 0.86 is a better value than 0.85.

```
usort($outcomes, 'sort_by_decimal');
function sort_by_decimal ($a, $b)
{
    return $a['Decimal'] - $b['Decimal'];
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Read the [`usort()` documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) again. It says in a *Note* on the description of parameter `value_compare_func`:

> `int callback ( mixed $a, mixed $b )`
>
> **Caution**
>
> Returning non-integer values from the comparison function, such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

Now I thinks it's clear than your function should read something like:

```
function sort_by_decimal ($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['Decimal'] < $b['Decimal']) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($a['Decimal'] > $b['Decimal']) {
        return +1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @axiac many thanks for the explanation. However it has now rearranged my array with the "best" as in the highest at the very bottom of the array, see : http://pastebin.com/NJ2KCB5M

Comment: It's up to your comparison function what is "the best". The function `usort()` sorts the elements "ascending", i.e. smallest first. If you need biggest first then change function `sort_by_decimal()` to return `-1` when `$a` is bigger than `$b` (and `+1` they are in the opposite relationship, of course).

Comment: Thanks very much @axiac reversing the logic has got that to work